# power supply reading drop from 12V to 4.8V why?

Tags: power-supply

I am testing few component that is bought off the shelf

wireless transmitter TS351
and camera KX181H

when i connect to the transmitter the power supply value remain at 12V but once i connect the camera the value drop to 4.8V. Do anyone know how to solve this problem that i am facing?

Thanks just found out the problem. Is as what u all say the current is too small. i send in a current of 300mA to make it work.

Comment: What's the supply?

Comment: on the specification of the camera it is stated that it needed a 12v

Comment: can the 12V supply enough power to feed both transmitter and camera?

Comment: what u mean by what's the supply? the power supply i use? is DC 12v

Comment: so i need to send in 24v instead? but wont the transmitter get burn out?

Comment: No, no...what do you use to provide the 12V? The problem is that it may not supply enough current...but to reply to comments use the @user tag

Comment: That 12V DC will be able to supply a certain current, for instance 100mA. If the transmitter uses 60mA and the camera would need another 50mA then that would be too much, and in many power supplies the voltage will sag.

Comment: @clabacchio i use a DC power supply model EX354RD. and the current i send is 0.15amp. as stated in the spec.

Comment: @JieLiang So set the current to a higher value. It won't hurt.

Comment: i go test again. hopefully can get something out of it this time. will try increasing the current.

Comment: Your transmitter needs 150mA and your camera needs 100mA; That's a total of **0.25A**. So you need to set your power supply to at least that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an EX354RD power supply, which you say provides 150mA. Isn't that a current limit you set? If the transmitter + camera together will need more than 150mA (not unlikely) then the current limiter will make the output voltage go down. Move the current limiter to a higher level.

**edit**
Like *m.Alin* says the specification for the TS351 says 150mA, and the KX181H needs 100mA. So the set current limit of 150mA is simply too low.

Comment: now i pump in 200mA to the transmitter only and the voltage drop to 5V. do u know y?

Comment: i just increase it to 300mA and is working now thanks.